# Prtotractor-Failing test cases as element not interactable for selecting from a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, protractor, click

css:

element.all(by.id('clonalityInput')).click();

element.all(by.cssContainingText('option','polyclonal')).click();

browser.sleep(5000);

[htmle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c15la.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Declare js click (inject script in console). and then just click any option directly. This `jsClick` doesn't care about interactivity of the element you're clicking

```
let jsClick = ($element) => browser.executeScript(
    "arguments[0].click();",
    $element.getWebElement()
);

let $option = $("option[value='395']");

await jsClick($option);
```